# System.out.println() is missing tabs ("\t") on some lines

Tags: java, android, system.out

I have a class, Variation, with three String fields: id, name, price. I populate a list of 25 of them with a random string of random characters, "name" plus + index (for name), and "price" + index (for price).

When I iterate through each Variation, I'm using:

`System.out.println(i + "\tid: " + variation.id + "\tname: " + variation.name + "\tprice: " + variation.price);`

My output is:

```
I/System.out: 0 id: 6N8D06S80DIEJQH9KJAG    name: name0 price: price0
I/System.out: 1 id: XCKGYA0W4YNKE25MRGKD    name: name1 price: price1
I/System.out: 2 id: UGI8Y6MCNDKEGR74F13L    name: name2 price: price2
I/System.out: 3 id: EHLXW3FGYSNE2XMFCT1P    name: name3 price: price3
I/System.out: 4 id: X1ONX4WZLWH41Z7UW3TE    name: name4 price: price4
I/System.out: 5 id: VG65ZGTDQ5C2TBYF26MZ    name: name5 price: price5
I/System.out: 6 id: HGK12SKUXSOZK0JDLL70    name: name6 price: price6
I/System.out: 7 id: DQJTDT108CWBJQOED06X    name: name7 price: price7
I/System.out: 8 id: YTRIZIMS5N5VZQUEJQ8L    name: name8 price: price8
I/System.out: 9 id: 59DGBOFULRZPJF7P53PN    name: name9 price: price9
I/System.out: 10    id: BLQ78XTDZQBUIXICWF2Q    name: name10    price: price10
I/System.out: 11    id: NY3PZ5RRIWAF92O5Z49D    name: name11    price: price11
I/System.out: 12    id: KPLYK1GFBIL92JPSYNK8    name: name12    price: price12
I/System.out: 13    id: 6MTB849NN6IZ2I5GSTF5    name: name13    price: price13
I/System.out: 14    id: 7718U4CXMD97YY1TUQ38    name: name14    price: price14
I/System.out: 15    id: GJOUN8U0SVIZDIH2WHAY    name: name15    price: price15
I/System.out: 16    id: D3CTCP9E7722LCRF07SM    name: name16    price: price16
I/System.out: 17    id: IWHDK9N49YC3DJOK0JY0    name: name17    price: price17
I/System.out: 18    id: 0ZTGE33GDWG42QGLDTHJ    name: name18    price: price18
I/System.out: 19    id: GRRJQ2KFLNFPS817WQCE    name: name19    price: price19
I/System.out: 20    id: GJSHJMLYXMMB5ZKDJ91B    name: name20    price: price20
I/System.out: 21    id: 2DE7RW6M50N3M7HE7IJG    name: name21    price: price21
I/System.out: 22    id: HBR2SVAHWXUP8QDQONIZ    name: name22    price: price22
I/System.out: 23    id: OAYUHH3138Q6PTRJX7HB    name: name23    price: price23
I/System.out: 24    id: FFIK3FR3K7ZKOYV77E2O    name: name24    price: price24
```

Here are the relevant parts of the code:

Main:

```
    List<Variation> variationsList = new ArrayList<>();

    void populateVariationsList() {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 25; i++)
            variationsList.add(new Variation(getRandomId(), "name" + i, "price" + i));
    }

    String getRandomId() {
        String CHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
        StringBuilder randomId = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (randomId.length() < 20)
            randomId.append(CHARS.charAt(rnd.nextInt(36)));
        return randomId.toString();
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        for(int i = 0; i < variationsList.size(); i++) {
            Variation variation = variationsList.get(i);
            System.out.println(i + "\tid: " + variation.id + "\tname: " + variation.name + "\tprice: " + variation.price);
        }
    }
```

Variation.java:

```
public class Variation {

    String id;
    String name;
    String price;

    public Variation(String id, String name, String price) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

It's not that important and I'm probably overlooking something silly, but can anyone see why it doesn't print all the tabs?

Comment: I suspect but can't verify right now that it is not missing tabs. In a lot of cases tabs are used for alignment, and therefore can have different sizes than you would expect.

Comment: Tabs are presents (checked in notepad++ by activating "show all characters" option). Tab size can vary. Behaviour is normal.

Comment: Do you mean it's probably just the console display and that the actual string does have tabs?

Comment: I suspect they are printed, but a tab does not represent a fixed number of spaces. A tab indents the subsequent data up to a certain column. If that can be done using just one space, then that is what happens. At your line with index 10, the indentation is already at the next tab column, so an additional tab with the maximum width is inserted.

Comment: awesome, thanks y'all! @PiRocks (

Comment: That's why some people prefer to indent their code with spaces rather than with tabs

Comment: @jhamon primarily due to the fact that the tab size can be configured in the various editors and IDEs, making tabs appear differently when rendered.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else has stated it's expected behavior. However, if you want uniform output (I'm pretty OCD about that) I would add an if else statement in the for loop of the onResume method that added a 0 before every single digit number, this should cause the tabs to all be uniform.

```
public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            for(int i = 0; i < variationsList.size(); i++) {
                Variation variation = variationsList.get(i);
                if(i < 10){
                    System.out.println( "0" + i + "\tid: " + variation.id + "\tname: " + variation.name + 
        "\tprice: " + variation.price);}
                else{
                     System.out.println(i + "\tid: " + variation.id + "\tname: " + variation.name + "\tprice: " + variation.price);
    }}}
```

Comment: Just use `printf`.